# After git merge workingbranch, how to remove the error "error: cannot run sublime: No such file or directory"

Tags: git, github, terminal, sublimetext

I'm using git on my terminal trying to merge the changes from my working branch to the master. I use the merge command and get an error that says "cannot run sublime:No such file or directory." and "unable to start editor 'sublime'."

I do not have sublime on my computer and do not want to use it. I would just like to get rid of these errors.

I continued on by adding, committing, and pushing the changes, and I saw that everything is now successfully showing up in Github. So it looks like the merge command successfully let me integrate my changes from the working branch to the master.

I checked my computer by searching for "sublime" in Launchpad and Finder, and I do not have the Sublime editor. I vaguely remember installing it once to try it out. But I seem to have uninstalled it.

Sheilas-MBP:violinportfolio Sheila$ git merge working --no-ff

error: cannot run sublime: No such file or directory

error: unable to start editor 'sublime'

Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.

Comment: Show the output of `git config core.editor`

Answer (score 2):

Either your system Git is configured to use sublime as the system-default editor (which seems unlikely), or you configured Git to use sublime as *your* default editor (which seems pretty likely).

The one bit of trouble here is finding out *how* you configured this, because there are a lot of ways to configure it.  The most common method is to use the `core.editor` setting:

```
git config --get core.editor
```

may print `sublime`, in which case you can use `git config` again to *un*-set that, and/or to choose whatever editor you do prefer.

In general, if you're *setting* your `core.editor` preference, you would want to use `git config --global`, as this sets your personal default for *all* Git repositories.  So if you want to use, say, `vim`, you would run:

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```

Presumably, you did this earlier to set it to `sublime`.  However, it's possible that you did instead:

```
git config core.editor sublime
```

earlier.  If so, that set sublime as your preferred editor for *this particular Git repository only*, and that setting will continue to override any *global* setting.  In that case, you'll need to *un-set* the local setting:

```
git config --unset core.editor
```

Should you wish to unset your global setting, you can use:

```
git config --global --unset core.editor
```

These are not the only places where you can set your preferred editor, but these are the most likely settings.  The other possibilities are environment variables: `$GIT_EDITOR`, `$VISUAL`, and `$EDITOR`.

#### Summary

- There are system (all users of this computer), global (all of *your* repositories on this computer), and local (*this* repository right now) settings for Git variables.  In the latest version of Git there are even per-work-tree settings that apply if you use `git worktree add`.  Use:

  ```
  git config --show-origin --list
  ```

  to see *all* settings and where they are set.
- The editor to use is chosen from the first one of these that is set:

  - `$GIT_EDITOR` (in the environment)
  - `core.editor` (from all Git configurations)
  - `$VISUAL` (in the environment)
  - `$EDITOR` (in the environment)
  - the compiled-in default (from your Git installation)

  These are the places to inspect for settings, if `core.editor` is not controlling which editor you use.

Comment: Looks like sublime was set as my editor for all Git configurations. I decided to unset the global setting until I learn more about using an editor with Git. Thanks!